# SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target - error while creating new project

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-tool-suite

While creating new spring starter project, I am facing this issue.

> SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path
>   to requested target - error while creating new project

I am using application in a corporate environment, hence I think it might be some issue of that. But whats the exact issue, I dont know.

[SunCertPathBuilderException error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvyCn.png)

Comment: Please edit your post to add the actual error, or add as a comment if you're unable to edit.

Comment: I have edited the question with the error image @kenny_k

Comment: Hard to say exacty what causes it. THe error is related to ssl certificates for connecting to start.spring.io over https. It could be a configuration issue on your machine itself or something in your network environment. If you are on a corporate network, you could try to consult with network / system administrator as they may have ideas on why you get the error and might be able to do something in the network configuration to fix it.

Comment: What version of java are you running ? I mean exact version, like 1.8.0_241-b07.